# How do I return by value for an "auto" return type function

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

Ok I don't know if I explained that very well with the title, so I'll just give an example. I'm trying to come up with a function that finds the median of a series of floating point numbers (and a little bit extra). Here is the function:

```
    //get the median of an unordered set of numbers of arbitrary type without modifying the
    //underlying dataset
    template <typename InputIterator>
    auto Median(
        InputIterator const cbegin, 
        InputIterator const cend,
        bool const abs = false // get the median of the absolute values rather than nominal values
        ) -> decltype(*cbegin)
    {
        typedef std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::value_type T;

        std::vector<T> data;
        data.reserve(std::distance(cbegin, cend));

        // get a copy of the values for sorting
        for (InputIterator it = cbegin; it != cend; ++it)
        {
            if (abs)
                data.push_back(std::abs(*it));
            else
                data.push_back(*it);
        }

        // find the median
        std::nth_element(data.begin(), data.begin() + data.size() / 2, data.end());

        return data[data.size() / 2];
    }
```

Here is the output if I try to compile this:

> warning C4172: returning address of local variable or temporary

I have tried replacing `decltype(*cbegin)` with `std::remove_reference<decltype(*cbegin)>::type` or `std::iterator_traits<decltype(*cbegin)>::value_type` but those don't compile either.

Is there a simple solution to this? How do I return the type to which `InputIterator` points?

EDIT: Here is a fixed version based on feedback:

```
    //get the median of an unordered set of numbers of arbitrary type without modifying the
    //underlying dataset
    template <typename RandomAccessIterator>
    typename std::iterator_traits<RandomAccessIterator>::value_type Median(
        RandomAccessIterator const cbegin,
        RandomAccessIterator const cend,
        bool const abs = false // get the median of the absolute values rather than nominal values
        )
    {
        typedef std::iterator_traits<RandomAccessIterator>::value_type T;

        std::vector<T> data(cbegin, cend);

        // find the median
        std::nth_element(data.begin(), data.begin() + data.size() / 2, data.end(),
            [abs](T const a, T const b)
        {
            return abs ? std::abs(b) > std::abs(a) : b > a;
        });

        return data[data.size() / 2];
    }
```

Comment: BTW `std::remove_reference<decltype(*cbegin)>::type ` should work if you stick `typename` in front of it `typename std::remove_reference<decltype(*cbegin)>::type`, but it probably is easier to use `std::iterator_traits` as the answer suggest.

Comment: BTW you can simplify the copying by using [`std::nth_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element) with a suitable predicate depending on `abs`.

Comment: You should rename the template type parameter. The implementation will not work with _InputIterators_, that are not also _ForwardIterators_.

Comment: This is why I keep coming back! Thanks everyone, all very helpful comments.

Comment: @nosid I've just checked the documentation for nth_element, should it be `RandomAccessIterator`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `iterator_traits` with template parameter, no decltype needed:

```
template <typename InputIterator>
typename std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::value_type
Median(
    InputIterator const cbegin, 
    InputIterator const cend,
    bool const abs = false
);
```

Note the `typename` keyword - it's what was missing in your attempts.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler is telling you that you are returning something temporary and, actually, you are.

The decltype(*cbegin) is a reference (so you can write code like `*it = 12`), so you are returning a reference to some value inside `data` which is temporary.

You can remove the reference by using `std::remove_reference<decltype(*cbegin)>::type`